# Nginx rewrite for subpaths with language parameter in between

Tags: nginx

With below line in the nginx-config a rewrite works from e.g.: [www.example.com](https://www.example.com) to [www.example.com/en](https://www.example.com/en).

```
  rewrite ^/$ /$lang/ redirect;
```

What is not working is a redirect from e.g.: [www.example.com/test](https://www.example.com/test) to [www.example.com/en/test](https://www.example.com/en/test)

How is it possible to make also those redirects?

Answer (score 1):

I solved it finally without regex.

Within the server-block first the `/de`, `/en` and any other available language is handled and at the very end the location for `/`, which makes a redirect to one of the languages, that the redirected-request lands in one of the language-locations.

```
server {

  location /de {
    # /de Rules here
  }

  location /en {
    # /en Rules here
  }

  location / {
    # $scheme:// for "http://" or "https://"
    # $host for the domain-name, like "example.com"
    # /$lang for the inserted lang-code like "/de" or "/en"
    # $request_uri for everything after the domain-name. From the original-question this would be "/test" (It comes with a slash in the front). 

    return 301 $scheme://$host/$lang$request_uri;
  }

}
```

The below code is just for information regarding how `$lang` is determined in order to avoid confusions. The first text of the nginx-configuration checks the browser-language, which can be overwritten by a cookie named "language" that can hold values like "de" or "en".

```
map $http_accept_language $hal_lang {
  default en;
  ~de de;
  ~en en;
}

map $cookie_language $lang {
  default $hal_lang;
  ~de de;
  ~en en;
}
```